# MacOS app bundle with GTK+ - no xcode

Tags: macos, c++11, gtk3, clang++, dylib

I am working on various C++ projects (School/Portfolio related) and I have been using the GTK+3 library for some of them. My apps are done and now I need to create the .app for my applications. I have been trying to get it working for a long time now and still without success. I am not working with xcode and compile my application with:

```
clang++ main.cpp _Scripts/Resources.cpp _Scripts/gui.cpp _Scripts/Game.cpp -o minesweeper `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -std=c++11
```

One of my projects was a replica of Minesweeper. My .app structure looks like this:

/Minesweeper.app

//Contents

///Info.plist

///MacOS

////minesweeper

////libatk-1.0.0.dylib

////libatkmm-1.6.1.dylib

////etc.dylib

///Resources

////MyAssets

I have done

```
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/duplicate.dylib" original.dylib
```

for every dylib int otool -L minesweeper. I then did

```
install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/glib/lib/originalDependency.dylib" "@executable_path/duplicateDependency.dylib" duplicate.dylib
```

for every dylib in otool -L duplicate.dylib. And finally I did

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/gdk-pixbuf/lib/original.dylib "@executable_path/duplicate.dylib" minesweeper
```

for all the dependencies. After all this, my app is still not working and it looks like it's the Gdk_pixbuf that's failing.

I found the the gdk_pixbuf/loaders folder, but I'm not sure if I need to link that or anything. Could anybody help me get my application working?

Regards,
Dani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I guess either no-one knew it or no-one wanted to spend 3849823 years to type an answer that MIGHT have helped me. Either way, I totally understand. I've spend a lot of time researching (also before asking the question) and I've written how I successfully created the app-bundle on [my website](https://extra.freetimedev.com/index.php?category=tutorials&subject=app-bundle). I hope it helps someone :)

Comment: 404, the link ins no longer valid.

Comment: You are correct. I stopped with my website. I hope you will find your solution

Comment: Can you give use basic instructions please?

Comment: Looks like archive.org has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20190514120648/https://extra.freetimedev.com/index.php?category=tutorials&subject=app-bundle

Comment: Sorry for not coming back at you. I haven't worked much with C++ since this project, so I haven't had the time to improve read more into creating a bundle. Basically, I used `$ otool -L myExecutable` to list all my dependencies, copied all those dependencies to a lib folder in my Resources folder. Then used the install_name_tool to change the decency path from my computer to the local lib folder in the Resources. It is very tedious and there must be a better way to do than I did. Hope you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the official information about how to bundle a GTK3 application on Mac OSX.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Bundling#Bundle_File

Comment: What about an example when using CMake (CPack) to create a macOS bundle?